# Lufthansa flight - Manchester to Ankara connecting at Munich. Do I go through security again?

Tags: schengen, transit, airport-security, munich

I'm flying from Manchester to Ankara with Lufthansa. I land at Munich then have an another flight to Ankara with an hour in between.

Will I have to go through security again? or show my passport to anyone? I have no idea where I have to go when I get off the plane in Munich and I only have an hour so don't want to miss my connection.

I arrive at terminal 2 and depart from terminal 2 (in munich).

thanks.

Comment: Is this on a single booking? Are the flights operated by the same airline?

Comment: If in doubt, you can always ask the cabin crew on the inbound leg for advice. They'll be familiar with the particular layout of the terminal in Munich.

Answer (score 2):

Munich has an international area, so if you stay in the same terminal, travel on the same ticket both legs and check in for the entire voyage, it is fairly likely that you will be able to transfer within the secure area.

Comment: But a security check is well within expectation and it is most likely that they will want to see your passport, as they seem to do that every time you board a plane in Europe.

Comment: Of course. The airport layout is made so that this can be easily changed for each flight, by simply opening one or another door. However they usually reduce the screening for connecting flights if they are confident that the originating airport has appropriate procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Look for signs saying "flight connections" and/or signs for your gate number.

AIUI germany trusts the UK on airport security. So you will normally be allowed straight into the international airside without a further security check. You don't need to go through immigration in germany since the UK and Turkey are both outside the Schengen area.

The airline will check your passport when you board to confirm your ID and that you have appropriate documentation for travel to your destination.

(note: this assumes your flights are on one ticket and therefore your baggage is checked through. You would be mad to book a connection this short on two seperate tickets).